# Implement Apache2 + Django + Vuejs into one platform

Tags: python, django, apache, vue.js, apache2

I am stuck with the Integration of Django and vuejs with apache2 into one single application. Basically `python manage.py runserver` can run the django. Instead of running `python manage.py runserver` apache2 can do the job. So what I need to do is; need to integrate the apache2 to run both Django (BackEnd)+ vuejs(FrontEnd). I couldn't find a solution for this. Please help me to solve the problem.
Currently Django is working along with apache2. But vuejs has no solution. To load vuejs application (FrontEnd), basically we need to run it separately in the terminal `npm run serve`. What I want to do is; when I run this code `service apache2 reload`. Backend (Django) and Frontend (vuejs) should load simultaneously.

Comment: You should build the front-end application and send the static files to the user there are plenty of resources out there. [This](https://dev.to/saymy__name__/hooking-up-django-and-vue-js-19j3) may help

Comment: @Shayan i need to implement with apache2

Comment: I know but it doesn't change anything you will run both front-end and back-end on the same port and configure the webserver to manage it whether it's Apache or Nginx or whatever.